# Change a state array with splice or filter, different reaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The "problem" is that if I put my state array in a variable, I splice her, and put that updated array in state, state is not updated, but in console.log it's allright.
If I do the same action with filter, the state is updated.

With splice :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!postLoad && !postError) {
      const filterIndex = getResponse.findIndex(
        (filter) => filter.id === postResponse.id
      );
      let arr = getResponse;
      arr.splice(filterIndex, 1);
      setGetResponse(arr);
      console.log(arr); // The result is as expected here
    }
  }, [postResponse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getResponse); // but this useEffect is not triggered because the state is not updated
  }, [getResponse]);
```

With filter :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!postLoad && !postError) {
        setGetResponse(
          getResponse.filter((filter) => filter.id !== postResponse.id)
        );
    }
  }, [postResponse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getResponse); // State updated !
  }, [getResponse]);
```

It works with filter, because filter create new filtered array I think, when splice only update current array, but this current array is in a new variable, so I cant understand... Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do -> `setGetResponse([...arr]);`,..

Comment: For the understand part -> `let a = [1,2,3]; let b = a; a.splice(0,1); console.log(a === b);`  Do you understand why the result of this is `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Understanding this behaviour requires understanding value and reference types, a general concept, and the way React triggers effects and re-renders, a React-specific concept.

## Passing by value and reference

In JavaScript, there are two ways of passing things around, by reference and by value. Certain types like `number`, `boolean` and `string` (value types) are passed by value, which means that their value is copied into a variable when they are assigned or used as a parameter in a function. As such, modifying a variable that has had a value type assigned to it will only modify the copy:

```js
const foo = 1;
let bar = foo; // assign foo (1) by value to bar. bar now holds the value 1
bar++; // this increments bar without modifying foo
console.log(foo); // 1, not modified by incrementing bar
console.log(bar); // 2
```

In contrast, instances of `object` and `array` (reference types) are passed by reference. When an instance of a reference type is assigned to a variable, that variable is assigned a reference to the instance, rather than a copy of the instance. As a consequence, assigning the same array to two variables means that both variables point to (share) the same array instance:

```js
const foo = [1];
const bar = foo; // assign bar to foo, now they both point to the same array
console.log(foo); // [1]
console.log(bar); // [1]
foo.push(2);
console.log(foo); // [1, 2]
console.log(bar); // [1, 2], because foo and bar point to the same array
```

Doing things like `push`ing to an array are called mutations, because they change the state of a reference type, without producing a new copy. As you noted in your question, `splice` is a mutating method, but `filter` is not.

So how does all this relate to React?

## Triggering effects in React

React triggers an effect when the effect's dependencies change. Dependencies are just state, and when state is updated with a state setter (`setGetResponse` in your example), React compares the value passed with the state's current value by reference. If they are not equal, effects depending on the updated state are triggered. In your example with splice, the following process takes place:

1. The value of `getResponse` is assigned by reference to arr. No copy of the array is created here.

```js
let arr = getResponse;
```

2. The array is mutated. Because `arr` and `getResponse` point to the same array, `getResponse` has been modified.

```js
arr.splice(filterIndex, 1);
```

3. React tries to do its magic. `getResponse` is compared with the value passed
   to `setGetResponse`, but they share the same reference and React decides that there has therefore been no change in state. For optimisation purposes, React won't trigger any sort of update if it thinks state hasn't changed, and so your effect is never triggered.

```js
setGetResponse(arr);
```

In your other example, `filter` returns a new array, and when React compares them, their references are not equal, and it therefore triggers your effect. All of this highlights why its important to not mutate state in React.

I hope this helped! Leave a comment if there's anything you're unsure about. There are also great articles about this on the React docs. Here's a few you might want to look at:

- https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state
- https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory
- https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot
- https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#my-component-rerenders-when-a-prop-is-an-object-or-array

Comment: Your answer is gold man !
I never knew that before about reference type in javascript.
I'll dont forget !
Hope to have your understanding one day !
Can I ask you where did you learn to code? School ? Independent training? (that's my case)

Comment: Glad to help! I write code as a hobby and mostly learn things by staring at documentation until it absorbs into my brain.

Comment: Okay !
I learn by practice tutorials, now I'll read more documentation before haha